# avcodec_send_frame returns "invalid argument"

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm trying to direct the output from opengl into a mp4 file.

Currently, I'm getting the error "Invalid input" from the call `avcodec_send_frame(c, frame)`. Why am I getting this error?

```cpp
class VideoCapture2
{
public:

    VideoCapture2(const char *filename, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, int framerate, unsigned int bitrate){

        avformat_alloc_output_context2(&avFormatContext, NULL, NULL, filename);
        if (!avFormatContext) {
            printf("Could not deduce output format from file extension: using MPEG.\n");
            avformat_alloc_output_context2(&avFormatContext, NULL, "mpeg", filename);
        }
        if (!avFormatContext)
            exit(1);

        avOutputFormat = avFormatContext->oformat;

        // Video Stream

        /* find the encoder */
        AVCodecID codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
        codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
        if (!codec) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not find encoder for '%s'\n",
                    avcodec_get_name(codec_id));
            exit(1);
        }

        pkt = av_packet_alloc();
        if (!pkt) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate AVPacket\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        avStream = avformat_new_stream(avFormatContext, NULL);
        if (!avStream) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate stream\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        avStream->id = avFormatContext->nb_streams-1;
        codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
        if (!codec_ctx) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not alloc an encoding context\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        codec_ctx->codec_id = codec_id;
        /* put sample parameters */
        codec_ctx->bit_rate = bitrate;
        /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
        if(width % 2 != 0)
            throw std::invalid_argument( "The width must be devisible by two" );

        if(height % 2 != 0)
            throw std::invalid_argument( "The height must be devisible by two" );

        codec_ctx->width = width;
        codec_ctx->height = height;
        /* frames per second */
        codec_ctx->framerate = (AVRational){framerate, 1};

        /* timebase: This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
        * of which frame timestamps are represented. For fixed-fps content,
        * timebase should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be
        * identical to 1. */
        avStream->time_base = (AVRational){ 1, framerate };
        codec_ctx->time_base       = avStream->time_base;

        codec_ctx->gop_size      = 10; /* emit one intra frame every twelve frames at most */
        codec_ctx->pix_fmt       = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

        /* Some formats want stream headers to be separate. */
        if (avOutputFormat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
            codec_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;


        frame = alloc_frame(codec_ctx->pix_fmt, codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height);
        if (!frame) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* copy the stream parameters to the muxer */
        ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(avStream->codecpar, codec_ctx);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not copy the stream parameters\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        // Color format Conversion

        sws = sws_getContext( codec_ctx->width
                            , codec_ctx->height
                            , AV_PIX_FMT_RGB32
                            , codec_ctx->width
                            , codec_ctx->height
                            , AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P
                            , SWS_FAST_BILINEAR // Change this???
                            , 0, 0, 0);

        
        // Check output file
        av_dump_format(avFormatContext, 0, filename, 1);

        /* open the output file, if needed */
        if (!(avOutputFormat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
            ret = avio_open(&avFormatContext->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
            if (ret < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not open '%s': %s\n", filename,
                        av_err2str(ret));
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        /* Write the stream header, if any. */
        ret = avformat_write_header(avFormatContext, &avDict);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output file: %s\n",
                    av_err2str(ret));
            exit(1);
        }

    }



    void addFrame(){
        fflush(stdout);

        /* Make sure the frame data is writable.
           On the first round, the frame is fresh from av_frame_get_buffer()
           and therefore we know it is writable.
           But on the next rounds, encode() will have called
           avcodec_send_frame(), and the codec may have kept a reference to
           the frame in its internal structures, that makes the frame
           unwritable.
           av_frame_make_writable() checks that and allocates a new buffer
           for the frame only if necessary.
         */
        ret = av_frame_make_writable(frame);
        if (ret < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not make the frame writable\n");
            exit(1); // Wait... you should throw error instead!
        }

        size_t nvals = 4 * codec_ctx->width * codec_ctx->height; //GL_BGRA
        pixels = (GLubyte *) realloc(pixels, nvals * sizeof(GLubyte)); // I don't think I need to do this every time since the size is constant
        glReadPixels(0, 0, codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

        // CONVERT TO YUV AND ENCODE
        ret =  av_image_alloc(frame->data, frame->linesize, codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 32);
        if (ret < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate the image\n");
            exit(1); // Wait... you should throw error instead!
        }

        // Compensate for OpenGL y-axis pointing upwards and ffmpeg y-axis pointing downwards        
        uint8_t *in_data[1] = {(uint8_t *) pixels + (codec_ctx->height-1)*codec_ctx->width*4}; // address of the last line
        int in_linesize[1] = {- codec_ctx->width * 4}; // negative stride

        sws_scale(sws, in_data, in_linesize, 0, codec_ctx->height, frame->data, frame->linesize);

        frame->pts = frame_order;
        frame_order++;

        /* encode the image */
        write_frame(avFormatContext, codec_ctx, avStream, frame, pkt);
    }




    void close()
    {
        write_frame(avFormatContext, codec_ctx, avStream, NULL, pkt);

        av_write_trailer(avFormatContext);

        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        sws_freeContext(sws);
        if (!(avFormatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
            /* Close the output file. */
            avio_closep(&avFormatContext->pb);

        avformat_free_context(avFormatContext);

    }

private:

    AVOutputFormat *avOutputFormat;
    AVFormatContext* avFormatContext = NULL;
    AVStream* avStream;
    AVDictionary *avDict = NULL; // "create" an empty dictionary

    GLubyte *pixels = NULL;
    struct SwsContext *sws;
    const AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *codec_ctx= NULL;

    // Should be ref counted??? https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.3/group__lavc__encdec.html
    AVFrame *frame;
    AVPacket *pkt;
   
    //
    int frame_order, ret;


    int write_frame(AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, AVCodecContext *c,
                        AVStream *st, AVFrame *frame, AVPacket *pkt)
    {
        int ret;



        // ERROR OCCURS HERE
        ret = avcodec_send_frame(c, frame); 
         // ERROR OCCURS HERE




        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error sending a frame to the encoder: %s\n",
                    av_err2str(ret));
            exit(1);
        }

        while (ret >= 0) {
            ret = avcodec_receive_packet(c, pkt);
            if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                break;
            else if (ret < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding a frame: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
                exit(1);
            }

            /* rescale output packet timestamp values from codec to stream timebase */
            av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, c->time_base, st->time_base);
            pkt->stream_index = st->index;

            /* Write the compressed frame to the media file. */
            log_packet(fmt_ctx, pkt);
            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_ctx, pkt);
            /* pkt is now blank (av_interleaved_write_frame() takes ownership of
            * its contents and resets pkt), so that no unreferencing is necessary.
            * This would be different if one used av_write_frame(). */
            if (ret < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing output packet: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        return ret == AVERROR_EOF ? 1 : 0;
    }

    void log_packet(const AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, const AVPacket *pkt)
    {
        AVRational *time_base = &fmt_ctx->streams[pkt->stream_index]->time_base;

        printf("pts:%s pts_time:%s dts:%s dts_time:%s duration:%s duration_time:%s stream_index:%d\n",
            av_ts2str(pkt->pts), av_ts2timestr(pkt->pts, time_base),
            av_ts2str(pkt->dts), av_ts2timestr(pkt->dts, time_base),
            av_ts2str(pkt->duration), av_ts2timestr(pkt->duration, time_base),
            pkt->stream_index);
    }

    AVFrame *alloc_frame(enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt, int width, int height)
    {
        AVFrame *frame;
        int ret;

        frame = av_frame_alloc();
        if (!frame)
            return NULL;

        frame->format = pix_fmt;
        frame->width  = width;
        frame->height = height;

        /* allocate the buffers for the frame data */
        ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate frame data.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        return frame;
    }


};
```

Comment: Have you checked c & frame are valid objects inside the function write_frame?

Comment: I can not see anything obviously wrong when inspecting them in the debugger. My guess would be that they either don't match somehow or I've forgotten to initialize some value... but that won't be easy to figure out

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be that I had missed calling `avcodec_open2(..)` now it works :)

```cpp
        /* open the codec */
        AVDictionary *opt = NULL;
        av_dict_copy(&opt, avDict, 0);
        ret = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, codec, &opt);
        av_dict_free(&opt);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open video codec: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
            exit(1);
        }

       // Then allocate frame...
        frame = alloc_frame(codec_ctx->pix_fmt, codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height);
        if (!frame) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
            exit(1);
        }
```

For reference, this is the full code (but the video quality is shit so you will have to tune that yourself)

```cpp
#ifndef VIDEO_CAPTURE2_H
#define VIDEO_CAPTURE2_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "../include/glad/glad.h" 
#include "finite_math.hpp"
#include <stdexcept>
extern "C" {
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libswscale/swscale.h>
    #include <libavutil/opt.h>
    #include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libavutil/opt.h>
    #include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
    #include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
}


// These exist to patch three functions for which gcc gets compiler errors
#ifdef av_err2str
#undef av_err2str
#include <string>
av_always_inline std::string av_err2string(int errnum) {
    char str[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    return av_make_error_string(str, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, errnum);
}
#define av_err2str(err) av_err2string(err).c_str()
#endif


#ifdef av_ts2str
#undef av_ts2str
#include <string>
av_always_inline std::string av_ts2string(int ts) {
    char str[AV_TS_MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    return av_ts_make_string(str, ts);
}
#define av_ts2str(ts) av_ts2string(ts).c_str()
#endif

#ifdef av_ts2timestr
#undef av_ts2timestr
#include <string>
av_always_inline std::string av_ts2timestring(int ts, AVRational *tb) {
    char str[AV_TS_MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    return av_ts_make_time_string(str, ts, tb);
}
#define av_ts2timestr(ts, tb) av_ts2timestring(ts, tb).c_str()
#endif


class VideoCapture2
{
public:

    VideoCapture2(const char *filename, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, int framerate, unsigned int bitrate){

        avformat_alloc_output_context2(&avFormatContext, NULL, NULL, filename);
        if (!avFormatContext) {
            printf("Could not deduce output format from file extension: using MPEG.\n");
            avformat_alloc_output_context2(&avFormatContext, NULL, "mpeg", filename);
        }
        if (!avFormatContext)
            exit(1);

        avOutputFormat = avFormatContext->oformat;

        // Video Stream

        /* find the mpeg1video encoder */

        /* find the encoder */
        AVCodecID codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
        codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
        if (!codec) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not find encoder for '%s'\n",
                    avcodec_get_name(codec_id));
            exit(1);
        }

        pkt = av_packet_alloc();
        if (!pkt) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate AVPacket\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        avStream = avformat_new_stream(avFormatContext, NULL);
        if (!avStream) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate stream\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        avStream->id = avFormatContext->nb_streams-1;
        codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
        if (!codec_ctx) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not alloc an encoding context\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        codec_ctx->codec_id = codec_id;
        /* put sample parameters */
        codec_ctx->bit_rate = bitrate;
        /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
        if(width % 2 != 0)
            throw std::invalid_argument( "The width must be devisible by two" );

        if(height % 2 != 0)
            throw std::invalid_argument( "The height must be devisible by two" );

        codec_ctx->width = width;
        codec_ctx->height = height;
        /* frames per second */
        codec_ctx->framerate = (AVRational){framerate, 1};

        /* timebase: This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
        * of which frame timestamps are represented. For fixed-fps content,
        * timebase should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be
        * identical to 1. */
        avStream->time_base = (AVRational){ 1, framerate };
        codec_ctx->time_base       = avStream->time_base;

        codec_ctx->gop_size      = 10; /* emit one intra frame every twelve frames at most */
        codec_ctx->pix_fmt       = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

        /* Some formats want stream headers to be separate. */
        if (avOutputFormat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
            codec_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

        /* open the codec */
        AVDictionary *opt = NULL;
        av_dict_copy(&opt, avDict, 0);
        ret = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, codec, &opt);
        av_dict_free(&opt);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open video codec: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
            exit(1);
        }


        frame = alloc_frame(codec_ctx->pix_fmt, codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height);
        if (!frame) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* copy the stream parameters to the muxer */
        ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(avStream->codecpar, codec_ctx);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not copy the stream parameters\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        // Color fromat COnversion

        sws = sws_getContext( codec_ctx->width
                            , codec_ctx->height
                            , AV_PIX_FMT_RGB32
                            , codec_ctx->width
                            , codec_ctx->height
                            , AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P
                            , SWS_FAST_BILINEAR // Change this???
                            , 0, 0, 0);

        
        // Check output file
        av_dump_format(avFormatContext, 0, filename, 1);

        /* open the output file, if needed */
        if (!(avOutputFormat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
            ret = avio_open(&avFormatContext->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
            if (ret < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not open '%s': %s\n", filename,
                        av_err2str(ret));
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        /* Write the stream header, if any. */
        ret = avformat_write_header(avFormatContext, &avDict);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output file: %s\n",
                    av_err2str(ret));
            exit(1);
        }

    }



    void addFrame(){
        fflush(stdout);

        /* Make sure the frame data is writable.
           On the first round, the frame is fresh from av_frame_get_buffer()
           and therefore we know it is writable.
           But on the next rounds, encode() will have called
           avcodec_send_frame(), and the codec may have kept a reference to
           the frame in its internal structures, that makes the frame
           unwritable.
           av_frame_make_writable() checks that and allocates a new buffer
           for the frame only if necessary.
         */
        ret = av_frame_make_writable(frame);
        if (ret < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not make the frame writable\n");
            exit(1); // Wait... you should throw error instead!
        }

        size_t nvals = 4 * codec_ctx->width * codec_ctx->height; //GL_BGRA
        pixels = (GLubyte *) realloc(pixels, nvals * sizeof(GLubyte)); // I don't think I need to do this every time since the size is constant
        glReadPixels(0, 0, codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

        // CONVERT TO YUV AND ENCODE
        ret =  av_image_alloc(frame->data, frame->linesize, codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 32);
        if (ret < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate the image\n");
            exit(1); // Wait... you should throw error instead!
        }

        // Compensate for OpenGL y-axis pointing upwards and ffmpeg y-axis pointing downwards        
        uint8_t *in_data[1] = {(uint8_t *) pixels + (codec_ctx->height-1)*codec_ctx->width*4}; // address of the last line
        int in_linesize[1] = {- codec_ctx->width * 4}; // negative stride

        sws_scale(sws, in_data, in_linesize, 0, codec_ctx->height, frame->data, frame->linesize);

        frame->pts = frame_order;
        frame_order++;

        /* encode the image */
        write_frame(avFormatContext, codec_ctx, avStream, frame, pkt);
    }




    void close()
    {
        write_frame(avFormatContext, codec_ctx, avStream, NULL, pkt);

        av_write_trailer(avFormatContext);

        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        sws_freeContext(sws);
        if (!(avFormatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
            /* Close the output file. */
            avio_closep(&avFormatContext->pb);

        avformat_free_context(avFormatContext);

    }

private:

    AVOutputFormat *avOutputFormat;
    AVFormatContext* avFormatContext = NULL;
    AVStream* avStream;
    AVDictionary *avDict = NULL; // "create" an empty dictionary

    GLubyte *pixels = NULL;
    struct SwsContext *sws;
    const AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *codec_ctx= NULL;

    // Should be ref counted??? https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.3/group__lavc__encdec.html
    AVFrame *frame;
    AVPacket *pkt;
   
    //
    int frame_order, ret;


    int write_frame(AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, AVCodecContext *c,
                        AVStream *st, AVFrame *frame, AVPacket *pkt)
    {
        int ret;

        // send the frame to the encoder
        ret = avcodec_send_frame(c, frame);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error sending a frame to the encoder: %s\n",
                    av_err2str(ret));
            exit(1);
        }

        while (ret >= 0) {
            ret = avcodec_receive_packet(c, pkt);
            if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                break;
            else if (ret < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding a frame: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
                exit(1);
            }

            /* rescale output packet timestamp values from codec to stream timebase */
            av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, c->time_base, st->time_base);
            pkt->stream_index = st->index;

            /* Write the compressed frame to the media file. */
            log_packet(fmt_ctx, pkt);
            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_ctx, pkt);
            /* pkt is now blank (av_interleaved_write_frame() takes ownership of
            * its contents and resets pkt), so that no unreferencing is necessary.
            * This would be different if one used av_write_frame(). */
            if (ret < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing output packet: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        return ret == AVERROR_EOF ? 1 : 0;
    }

    void log_packet(const AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, const AVPacket *pkt)
    {
        AVRational *time_base = &fmt_ctx->streams[pkt->stream_index]->time_base;

        printf("pts:%s pts_time:%s dts:%s dts_time:%s duration:%s duration_time:%s stream_index:%d\n",
            av_ts2str(pkt->pts), av_ts2timestr(pkt->pts, time_base),
            av_ts2str(pkt->dts), av_ts2timestr(pkt->dts, time_base),
            av_ts2str(pkt->duration), av_ts2timestr(pkt->duration, time_base),
            pkt->stream_index);
    }

    AVFrame *alloc_frame(enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt, int width, int height)
    {
        AVFrame *frame;
        int ret;

        frame = av_frame_alloc();
        if (!frame)
            return NULL;

        frame->format = pix_fmt;
        frame->width  = width;
        frame->height = height;

        /* allocate the buffers for the frame data */
        ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate frame data.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        return frame;
    }


};
#endif
```